# Is there any possibilities that we can use “in” here in this case?

Tags: prepositions

[image: toy cars ? the table]

> There are some toy cars ___ the table.

The first preposition came to my mind was “**under**”, which I think most people would think of first. 
Can we use “**in**” here?  The board and four legs may form a space. The toy cars are right in there.

What other prepositions do you think are also situable?

Answer (score 2):

In the picture the toys are ***under*** the table, regardless of the space under it. So no, you cannot use ***in*** when describing toys in that picture.

Additionally: *The cars are between the table legs*

---

If you had a table like this, then you could use

*Get the balls. They are in your table*. [image]

But even then I would use *Get the balls. They are in your table drawers*.